# DAX SUM DISTINCT values by groups

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to PBI/DAX.
I have a table called Opp Recs with a few columns: `Group1`, `NumEmp`, `OppRec`, `AcctNum`.
I want to sum the `NumEmp` column if `Group1` equals `"Corp Employees"` but only for unique `AcctNum`.

I used this formula but realized `NumEmp` was double counted for dup `AcctNums`:
`**Corp # Emps = CALCULATE(SUM('Opp Recs'[NumEmp]), 'Opp Recs'[Group1] = "Corp Employees")**`

How can I sum `NumEmp` correctly?

Sample Data:

| Group1 | NumEmp | OppNum | AcctNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Corp Employees | 450 | 000030689 | A0000123 |
| Corp Employees | 450 | 000030624 | A0000123 |
| Corp Employees | 150 | 000030118 | A0000662 |
| Small Bus Emp | 5 | 000030637 | A0000737 |
| Small Bus Emp | 37 | 000030738 | A0000755 |
| Corp Employees | 100 | 000030639 | A0000784 |
| Corp Employees | 100 | 000030616 | A0000784 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit:*** Based on the new requirement specified in the comments, please use this version of the code:

```
S =
CALCULATE (
    SUMX (
        SUMMARIZE ( Corporate, Corporate[NumEmp], Corporate[AcctNum] ),
        Corporate[NumEmp]
    ),
    KEEPFILTERS ( Corporate[Group1] = "Corp Employees" ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Corporate, Corporate[Group1] )
)
```

[image]

***Code based on the original requirement:***

If you want to get the grand total for everything for unique AcctNum and Corp Employees then use this

```
VAR IsUniqueAcct =
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( Corporate[AcctNum] ),
        CALCULATE (
            COUNTROWS ( Corporate ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( Corporate, Corporate[AcctNum] ),
            Corporate[Group1] = "Corp Employees"
        ) = 1
    )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Corporate[NumEmp] ), IsUniqueAcct )
RETURN
    Result
```

[image]

If you want to segregate the total of NumEmp based on the AcctNum then use this:

```
S = 
VAR IsUniqueAcct =
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( Corporate[AcctNum] ),
        CALCULATE (
            COUNTROWS ( Corporate ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( Corporate, Corporate[AcctNum] ),
            Corporate[Group1] = "Corp Employees"
        ) = 1
    )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Corporate[NumEmp] ),
        KEEPFILTERS ( IsUniqueAcct ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( Corporate, Corporate[AcctNum] )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for a response. It isn't quite the results I'm hoping for. 
Yes, I want to total everything for unique AcctNum and Corp Employees.
Your first example seems to remove all rows with matching AcctNum, A0000123 and A00000784.
Four rows are removed so the SUM is 150 [A0000662]. The SUM should be 450+150+100 = 700.

Comment: You mentioned in the original post that you only want the SUM for unique Account Number. Has the requirement changed?

Comment: Oh!!!! Sorry, my bad. I want the sum of NumEmp for distinct AcctNum for Corp Employees. Your solution is correct based on my original request. I just worded it incorrectly. opps

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to be sure, please check the update solution above.

Comment: You're awesome!!!! Your solution worked. Thank you so much. I'm saving all of you examples for future use. Now I just need to improve how I post my questions. Thank you!!

Comment: Sure, enjoy DAX!

Comment: what if i need Group1 multiple conditions, how to write right syntax? Corp Employees and Small Bus Emp